# How to make it so that FileWriter doesn't continuously replace line one with input instead of just moving onto the next line?

Tags: java, filewriter

I'm using FileWriter and I have it so that when a user answers a question, the linked text is added to the attached text file but instead of each .write(""); going to the next line in the txt file, it just keeps replacing line 1, when I use line separator, or (\n) it just adds blank lines underneath while continuing the replace the text on line 1.

```
System.out.println("Please choose your sub size \n 1 - six inch ($7.19) \n 2 - twelve inch ($10.99) \n  Please enter '1' or '2'");
sub.size = input.nextLine();

// filtering all input other than '1' and '2'
while (!sub.size.equals("1") && !sub.size.equals("2")) {
    System.out.println("Please enter '1' or '2'");
    sub.size = input.nextLine();
}

//adding to the price depending on chosen size
if (sub.size.equals("1")) {
    sub.price = sub.price + 7.19;
    try {
        FileWriter orderTaker = new FileWriter("subOrder.txt");
        orderTaker.write("6 inch Sub");
        //orderTaker.write(System.lineSeparator());
        orderTaker.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[First input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfNkw.png)
[After second input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Cal3.png)

Tried bufferedWriter off of someone's suggestion, have tried (\n), have tried (\r\n), have tried lineSeparator

Comment: Hint: look at the other constructors of FileWriter that you could use...

Comment: Keep the FileWriter open, instead of opening and closing it for every line.

Comment: Please copy/paste the output instead of using screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem lies in the constructor you are using. If you do not want to override the existing file contents, you need to use the [`FileWriter(File, boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter-java.io.File-boolean-) constructor, which takes a boolean parameter called `append`. Set append to true, and it will add your data to the end of the file instead of overwriting it.

A better solution, however, would be to keep your FileWriter opened until you are finish collecting all the orders. Opening and closing a file handle repeatedly will result in bad performance.

Here's an example:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean acceptingOrders = true;

try (FileWriter orderTaker = new FileWriter("subOrder.txt", true)) {
    while (acceptingOrders) {
        System.out.println("1 - six inch ($7.19)");
        System.out.println("2 - twelve inch ($10.99)");
        System.out.println("Please enter '1' or '2' or 'done'");

        boolean invalidInput = true;
        String userInput = input.nextLine();
        do {
            if (userInput.equals("1")) {
                sub.size = userInput;
                sub.price = sub.price + 7.19;
                orderTaker.write("6 inch Sub\n");

                invalidInput = false;
            } else if (userInput.equals("2")) {
                sub.size = userInput;
                sub.price = sub.price + 10.99;
                orderTaker.write("12 inch Sub\n");

                invalidInput = false;
            } else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
                acceptingOrders = false;
                invalidInput = false;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please enter '1' or '2' or 'done'");
                userInput = input.nextLine();
            }
        } while (invalidInput);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("An error occurred.");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```